# SQL: Adding several values with same ID from different COLUMNS

Tags: sql, count

TABLE 1 (ODETAILS):

[image]

TABLE 2 (ORDERS):

[image]

MY question is: How can I print out the following by using these two tables?

```
+------+-----+
| ONO  | QTY |
+------+-----+
| 1020 |   9 |
| 1021 |   4 |
| 1022 |   2 |
| 1023 |   2 |
+------+-----+
```

Comment: I see no requirement for the ORDERS table in producing the desired output. What are you using from the ORDERS table?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the SUM aggregate function and a Group By on the Order Number:

```
SELECT ONO, SUM(QTY) AS QTY 
FROM ODETAILS
GROUP BY ONO
```

Comment: You were right Chris. But why?? 
I tried: 
`SELECT o.ono, COUNT(od.qty) 

FROM orders o 
JOIN odetails od
ON o.ono = od.ono
GROUP BY o.ono`


What is the difference between COUNT and SUM? ....

Comment: Count will simply tell you the number of records matching the criteria.  So each line in your table would Count for 1.  Sum actually adds up the actual Values in the column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to elaboratemore but here is a shot in the dark!

```
SELECT ODETAILS.ONO, ORDERS.QTY
FROM ODETAILS CROSS JOIN ORDERS;
```

Ted.